# Organic Groups email group members permission denied

Tags: 7, users, emails, organic-groups

I have a fresh D7 installation with the latest [OG](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) modules and a few groups, users, and group articles added. However, I'm getting "Access Denied" when I click "Email People" in the group page. OG Email Blast is enabled and this problem happens regardless of setting the admin user as group manager and administrator member of the group. The problem happens for all users.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.